# Visual studio 2015 template installation "error"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a fresh installation of windows 10 and visual studio 2015 enterprise edition. I'm trying to install one of the templates found in the "new project"-dialogue window, in my case the "Install Tools for Apache Cordova Update 2", but none of the non-installed templates work, they all return the same dialogue window titled "Setup - Usage" with lots of different flags that can be used in the setup process.

I have tried to reinstall VS, and when googling I couldnt find anything about this "error".

I was not allowed to post an image since I do not have 10 rep yet, but I can upload it somewhere else if that is allowed.

edit: To clarify, this is the steps used to try to install the Cordova template:
1. File -> New -> Project
2. Navigate to "Install Tools for Apache Cordova Update 2", and dubbleclick it.
3. A dialogue window appears, I click "Install".
4. The "Setup - Usage" dialogue window appears, instead of the installation window and confirmation.

The window that shows up: http://1drv.ms/1jaq3Tc

Comment: Upload a picture somewhere else and post a link.

Comment: added a pic of the "error"